# Automatically select a default image in a dialog using Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, webkit

I want a small feature (in VB) that will allow me to automatically select a default image after opening a dialog from a Java script and attach this photo automatically with an offine-type file input to load a picture automatically - without user intervention in the dialog box (or selection or click on the "yes" button) -
in a web page control is used webkitbrowser.

The problem is that this code:

```
WebKitBrowser1.StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('id_de_input_type_file').click();")
```

Displays the dialog box and waits for the user response, while I want this selection to run automatically.

Comment: You mean, select the image once, and then the next time the app runs, use that image again?  Specify your plaform: web? winforms? wpf? etc.

Comment: No, I said that I am working on Winform with a webkitbrowser and I want to make a picture that changes automatically in every click and run the OpenFileDialog with or without the appearance of the latter in a way that allows me to clic button using vb code and select the existing photo in the OpenFileDialog that I specify url.
 in JavaScript it is not allowed safety issue, I would like if it's possible with vb and display this picture on my inpute type file  in this page Apparent in the webkitbrowser control. Thanks in advance